# Pandas DataFrame Groupby two columns and get sum

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

This should be an easy one, but somehow I couldn't find a solution that works.

I have a pandas dataframe which looks like this:

```
    No. Type        Number            Date          Price     ID
0   1   bike        19122104405       21-12-2019    2000.00   1
1   2   bike        210171-ORGNL      21-12-2019    1000.00   1
2   3   mobile      BM20321000832531  21-12-2019    830.62    1
3   4   bike        375422-ORGNL      21-12-2019    2500.00   2
4   5   mobile      AACCK9882F        21-12-2019    474.81    3
5   6   car         MH1952G0          21-12-2019    1350.00   1
6   7   internet    BM2032I000858443  27-12-2019    242.76    4
7   8   internet    FT20321000424478  27-12-2019    1189.24   1
8   9   bike        6396              30-12-2019    500.00    5
9   10  car         83254             01-01-2020    1000.00   5
```

I want to group by ID and Type and take its sum So it would look like the dataframe below:

```
ID          BillType    Ext_invoice_amount  
35657       bike        2500.00
3757        bike        3000.00
3757        car         1350.00
3757        internet    1189.24
3757        mobile      830.62
3798        mobile      474.81
487         bike        500.00
487         car         1000.00
9657        internet    242.76
```

Here is what I tried

```
grouped_sum = df.groupby(['ID','BillType']).sum()
```

Could use some help

Comment: some problem with `grouped_sum = df.groupby(['EmployeeID','BillType']).sum()` ? Or need `grouped_sum = df.groupby(['EmployeeID','BillType'], as_index=False).sum()` ?

Comment: Which column in the dataframe is the `EmployeeId`?

Comment: @JANO My bad.. I have edited this